# Add a parameter to addGestureRecognizer?

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, sender

I'm sorry but the title may be incorrectly redacted…

I've got an if statement in my viewDidLoad :

```
if segueDestination.isEmpty {
} else {
let path = "somePath"
let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "goToA:")
addXib?.viewOutlet.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
print(segueDestination)
}
```

I need to access the path constant in goToA:

```
func goToA(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, sender: AnyObject) {

    print(sender.path)

}
```

But I get an "ambiguous use of 'path'" error in XCode… I can't figure why and it drives me crazy !!!

Comment: That is not possible the way you are trying to do it! The action method can either have zero parameters or exactly one, the `gestureRecognizer`. There is no way to pass along other data as well. You have to store the path somewhere else and associate the `gesture` in some way with it.

Comment: God damn it !Ok thanks !

Comment: In `goToA`, you can get access to the view that the gesture recognizer is attached to with `gestureRecognizer.view`, so make sure that your view can access that data that is needed, then you can get to it.